# Deep well pump malfunction

Tags: water, pump

My deep well pump (100 feet) does not activate automatically. Instead, I have to pour 2-3 gallons of water to activate it. The pressure is about 30. After a while, it will stop altogether and I have to call the plumber who says the foot valve and/or the rubber gasket is/are broken. He and his crew would pull out the length of the pipes replace the broken parts and the pump will do well. After a while, it will lose pressure and I have to go back to pouring water until it stops working. This cycle has happened 3x in the past 4 years and I am tired of paying the plumber and buying parts for replacement. Right now I am again pouring water to activate it. Sooner or later it will stop.  What do you suggest??

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If one of the answers is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept it. And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm. **Pour water to activate it** sounds like a Jet pump. Replace it with a submersible pump (Two-wire is more reliable than 3-wire in the modern era, I think - not to mention the wire costs less and on the comparable models I was comparing could also be one size smaller.)

Jet pumps are a holdover from a bygone era when electric motors were much less reliable, and are both troublesome and shockingly inefficient (power in compared to water out) .vs. a deep well submersible pump.

Comment: I replaced a jet with a submersible this year , measure your well casing and get a submersible, I use a large amount of water and my power bill did drop after replacing the jet with a submersible. And I have more water (higher flow rate) +

Comment: Will research your suggestion and confirm with a Master Plumber.

Answer (score 0):

How old is the well pump? These pumps do not last forever and it may well be time to pull up that 100 feet of pipe and replace the well pump.

Comment: The pump is 4 years old. The pipes have been replaced twice already. First, the GI pipes got rusted. Changed to 1st grade PVC. The pump now stops after a while. I am still told by the plumber that it is the foot valve.